# Sqlite How to treat Empty Strings as Null values?

Tags: database, sqlite

I have many tables that look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO TABLE foo (id, name) VALUES (1, '');
```

However, it appears that I can insert empty strings into the `name` column. Oracle for example prevents this from happening.

Is it possible to get Sqlite to treat empty strings as null, other than by adding the following check constraint on every table?

```
CHECK (name <> '')
```

Comment: The `check` constraint seems like the correct solution.

Comment: Oracle prevents that from happening because Oracle is brain-dead. In proper tri-value logic, an empty string is *not* the same thing as a null value, despite what Larry though when Oracle was first designed :-) In any case, what about a single space, or `.`, or a dozen other things people will use to get around your constraint? Do you really want to catch all these?